# How could I aggregate among multiple collections at once with loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Suppose Each collection has these common fields `birthday, gender`

## How could I get the grouped `birthday` with `year` by **group**

### expected result

- group **r01** `{id: 1987, count: 21121}, {id: 1988, count: 22}, ...`

> The output should count for `user_vip_r01` and `user_general_r01`

- group **r15** `{id: 1986, count: 2121}, {id: 1985, count: 220}, ...`

> The output should count for `user_vip_r15` and `user_general_r15`

I know how to write the `group by year` query,

But don't know how to write an **loop** to iterate all my collection with javascript.

And what if the collection name is part of irregular,

Something like `user_old_r01`, `user_new_r01`, `user_bad_r01`, should all be processed in group `r01`,

Is it possible to use `regex` to get it ?

## group by year

```
pipeline = [
  { '$group':
    '_id': '$year': '$birthday'
    'count': '$sum': 1
  }
  { '$sort': '_id': 1 }
]
cur = db[source_collection].runCommand('aggregate',
  pipeline: pipeline_work.concat([{ '$out':  output_collection_name}])
  allowDiskUse: true)
```

## collection list

```
"user_vip_r01",
"user_vip_r15",
"user_vip_r16",
"user_vip_r17",
"user_vip_r18",
"user_vip_r19",
"user_vip_r20",
"user_vip_r201",
....
"user_general_r01",
"user_general_r15",
"user_general_r16",
"user_general_r17",
"user_general_r18",
"user_general_r19",
"user_general_r20",
"user_general_r201",
...
```

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. Instead of maintaining two collections with the same data, you should use one collection using additional field(s) denoting the difference of the entries, if there are some.  Remember, data modeling in MongoDB is about the questions you are going to ask (like your pipeline), unlike SQL data modeling.